# Running the same function, after several specific amounts of time

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an audio file, that loops forever. Each time it says a word, I want to run a function. I can't find any way to detect the word in the audio file, so moving on. I have a list of timestamps in the file when I would like to run that function. For example,

- 0:03 = run My function;
- 0:12 = run My function;
- ... And so on

I would really like to not use jQuery. I went with the **setTimeout();** javascript thingy.(whatever it's  called). Pretty much, because the song loops, I need the code to loop too. My function is a counter that ads 1 each time the function is run. So I need help finding a set of instructions in a series that loops, using the setTimeout() thingy. Thanks.

Comment: First you want to make a function with all the timers that call your other function. Then you use `setInterval()` to loop your timers function at the length of your audio loop. Though I suspect this will start causing you trouble the longer it runs. Because the audio file might have milliseconds that you can't see. It will most likely run out of sync eventually. Not to mention connection speeds (lag if you will) and users using the browser's build in function to kill the audio.

Comment: I mean, if a user has a slow connection speed, the browser might still be busy downloading the audio file while your javascript code is already running. In that case it would be completely out of sync. So you'll have to somehow ensure the user has the audio file before you initiate your javascript code.

Comment: @icecub it's just for a toyish website, so it doesn't matter if It is off a little

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use setInterval(); so in your instance you can

```
let i = 0;
setInterval(function() { 
   alert(i+1); 
}, 1000);
```

Which will increment by 1 every second.

Comment: `i+1` This will cause issues. The function inside `setInterval()` is a callback function. So any variable declared outside of it will be out of scope. And if you declare it inside, it will reset on each loop.

Comment: @icecub yea thats what I meant by just the I. I should have been more clear. thanks